# Is it possible to make a cut from ortho view through the whole object that is measured 1cm from this edge?

Tags: modeling

Red line is where I would like to cut straight through, 1cm from the loop selected. I couldn't seem to find any previous posts that described exactly what I want here. Anyone know if it is possible to make a cut like this?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the answer from @Robin-Betts is working in many cases, there are those situations where the cut would go through different loops and thus a loop cut with later adjustment would not work.

Here a solution that should work no matter what:

1. **Select** a vertex that lies along an edge from where you want the precise distance.
2. **Duplicate** the vertex with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and press <kbd>Z</kbd> to make sure it stays on that axis. **Move** the vertex above the object.
3. **Press** <kbd>G</kbd> followed by <kbd>Y</kbd> in this case to restrict the movement again and then enter the distance you desire the cut to be made at.(I used a specific distance to showcase the mentioned situation with a possible cut over multiple loops.)
4. **Extrude** with <kbd>E</kbd> from the vertex once to the left and once to the top and **create** a face (you can restrict the extrusion with <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd>, but it's not absolutely needed here, as only the first duplicated vertex is needed to be precisely where it is). A triangle face is fine, as it's just a workaround to get an anchor for the knife tool. For some reason a single vertex as well as an edge won't let you snap to it with the knife tool.
5. Now you can **activate** the **knife tool** with <kbd>K</kbd> and it will find the vertex we first duplicated to use as **startpoint**.
6. **Activate** the **angle constraint** with <kbd>**C**</kbd> and **cut through** 
   with <kbd>**Z**</kbd> and pull the cut under the object to have the cut encompass the entire object.
7. **Accept** with <kbd>LMB</kbd> and **confirm** the cut with <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You can now delete the knife anchor face.

Here a more visual explanation:

[image]

Comment: Ahhhh, I had tried making that extra vertex for the cut but I didn't have what it took for the knife to anchor. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yup. :) Nice move. IMO,  In hard-surface, it's often a very smooth way to work, to 'think like a carpenter'  and have bits/jigs around, that aren't part of the model, but serve as snap targets, or stashed lengths/angles.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create your new edge-loop any old where in the desired face-loop: Either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, or <kbd>K</kbd> the Knife tool with <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through.
2. <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> slide the new edge-loop all the way to the '0' side of the containing face-loop, and left-click to accept.
3. <kbd>G</kbd>(move) the new edge-loop, and left-click to accept, so you can..
4. .. Enter '1cm' in the appropriate field (here, 'X',) of the Adjust Last Operation panel.

If the measured move is not conveniently aligned to a World axis, you may have to set the Transform Orientation to 'Local', or even create one of your own.

Comment: @Robin_Betts Thank you much, this will be very useful to me going forward